# Pegar valores que não foram utilizados dentro do bd

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Tenho uma tabela com vários códigos de produtos:

EX:
1, 2, 3 ,4 , 5, 15, 20, 21, 22, 45, 60...100

Gostaria se saber se existe alguma query pra pegar os códigos que ainda não foram utilizados nos registros?
No exemplo acima o codigo 5 pulo para o codigo 15, nesse caso gostaria de pegar os codigos 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, e assim por diante.

Comment: Vitor, aconselho a você incluir mais detalhes. Tais como: detalhes da sua tabela, quando configura que um `ID` destes foi usado?? É inserido em outra tabela? Qual o funcionamento? Aí sim poderemos lhe ajudar. Caso sejam em tabelas distintas é bastante simples, basta usar um `NOT EXISTS` ou `EXISTS` depende de onde partirá a consulta. Exemplo `SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2);`

Comment: @ Fernando A.W. , Estes registros são inseridos manualmente, o que ocasionou essa bagunça nos código de pular alguns na hora do cadastro.

Comment: mas eles ficam na mesma tabela? Acho que entendi, devido a ser `insert` manual você quer pegar os valores que não foram utilizados.

Comment: Correto  Fernando A.W., pegar os registros dentro de apenas uma tabela!

Comment: Vitor, de uma olhada na resposta que coloquei, deve atender sua necessidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vitor, eu faria da seguinte forma.

Pegaria o valor: `MAX()` da sua tabela. Digamos que seja 100. Em seguida, geraria uma tabela temporária com os valores de 1 a 100.

```
CREATE TABLE `incr` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Em seguida uma procedure para alimentar esta tabela com o intervalo de dados que você quer buscar.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 100;
  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    INSERT incr VALUES (NULL);
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Em seguida, executamos a procedure:

```
CALL dowhile();
SELECT * FROM incr;
```

Resultado:

```
Id
1
2
3
...
100
```

Depois disto fazemos a consulta utilizando o `NOT EXISTS`para pegar os valores que não estão na sua tabela:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM incr
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SUA_TABELA_AKI
                    WHERE SUA_TABELA_AKI.ID= incr.ID);
```

E desta forma você terá todos os códigos não existentes na sua tabela.

Comment: Fernando, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @Vitor.. Qualquer coisa grita aí. Só lhe peço para que se resolveu o problema, marcar como "resposta", assim facilita para o pessoal, em possíveis buscas.

Comment: Obrigado! deu certinho! Obrigado pela dica.